# Problem with sending Image from React to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, reactjs, flask

I have The Following **ReactJS+HTML** code :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const sendImage = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let fileToUpload = image
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload)
    
    fetch('/api/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Accept': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
      }).then(resp => {
        resp.json().then(data => {console.log(data)})
      })
    }
```

```html
  return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="container mt-5 pt-5 pb-5" encType="multipart/form-data">

      <div className="form-inline justify-content-center mt-5">
        <label htmlFor="image" className="ml-sm-4 font-weight-bold mr-md-4">Image : </label>
        <div className="input-group">
          <input onChange={(e) => {setImage(e.target.files[0])}} type="file" id="image" name="file" accept="image/*" className="file-custom"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="input-group justify-content-center mt-4">
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-md btn-primary">Upload...</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  )
}
```

And The Following **Python-Flask** code:

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/upload', methods=['POST'])
def handle_form():
    files = request.files
    file = files.get('file')
    """
      CODE TO HANDLE FILE
    """
    return jsonify({
        'success': True,
        'file': 'Received'
    })


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html");   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

The Problem is that when I Submit the form, the file doesn't get sent to the backend.

Respond when printing files & file from **Python-Flask** :

```py
ImmutableMultiDict([])
None
```

How Can I fix This Issue?

**Please Note :**

When I use Plain HTML (non-React based form) It works out perfectly, but when using React based form it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but have you tried submitting a normal, non-React based form to the same URL? Just to make sure that it's the python aspect that's wrong, rather than the React.

Comment: Yes, when I use a non-React based form Everything works out perfectly, but I want to use The React based form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally transition towards submitting the form in a different way. Consider doing it like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="container mt-5 pt-5 pb-5" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div className="form-inline justify-content-center mt-5">
        <label htmlFor="image" className="ml-sm-4 font-weight-bold mr-md-4">Image :  </label>
        <div className="input-group">
            <input type="file" id="image" name="file" 
            accept="image/*" className="file-custom"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div className="input-group justify-content-center mt-4">
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-md btn-primary">Upload,,,</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    
    const Upload = async() => {
      await fetch('/api/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      }).then(resp => {
        resp.json().then(data => {console.log(data)})
      })
    }
    Upload();
  }
```

This way, you're actually still using the browser-default Form system without having to reinvent any wheels, but it's still all within react and handled by a post request

I googled how to submit a formData with `fetch` api, and one article suggested not using the Content-Type header, so I stripped that out.

Alternatively, consider using `axios`:

```
          axios
            .post('/api/upload', formData)
```

Comment: Thank You, I changed my handleSubmit function to match yours and removed Content-Type & Accept, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: cool, you didn't have to change to axios? interesting.

Comment: I actually made a little test project to see if I could send up the formData you did originally, controlling the `image` state in React code - and it worked! I did essentially the same thing you did, creating a brand new `formData` from scratch and appending the file to it. It might have only been the headers that were wrong for you in the end.

Comment: Can you post the code where you used this approach. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: the react code i used is in here, https://jsfiddle.net/qszxdyeh/